# CPP. Error: Invalid operands to binary expression "=="

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```cpp
bool isSomething(string val, string lst) {
for(auto c = 0; c < lst.size(); c++) {
        if(val == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

Code produces the following error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__ndk1::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') and 'int')

        if(val == c) {

           ~~~ ^  ~
```

I tried to change the return type, it didn't help, I'm rewriting the code, and I don't know.
I think we should overload the == operator, but I'm not sure if it's possible, and I don't quite know how to do it.

Comment: You can't compare a `string` to an `int`. They are different types. If `val` is supposed to hold an integer value, why is it of type `string`? Or alternatively, why do you compare `val` to the integer index at all? Why is the type of `lst` also `string`? Maybe it is supposed to be a _list_ of `string`s? What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: I have tried changing each of the arguments to int, but still there are errors in the console, there are more of them.

Comment: Maybe explain what the function is supposed to do, then. Right now we can only guess.

Comment: It is not about trying different types until it happens to work. Instead start with thinking about what the function is supposed to do, what the types of its input need to be for this function and then go on from there.

Comment: An example of using the function: ```bool isNumber(string charc) {
    string numbers = "0123456789";
    string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return isSomething(charc, numbers);
};```

Comment: EDIT YOUR QUESTION. Don't clarify in the comments.

Comment: However, I would recommend looking at [`<cctype>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype) as it appears you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Tim Start with implementing `isNumber` without delegating to a `isSomething` function. You can do that later. Also start considering first only `charc` with length `1` and then go to higher length. Think about how you would perform the function manually on paper step-for-step before writing any code and then write the code to mimic your on-paper procedure. A `string` contains many characters and you can access them by index with `[`/`]`. You should only compare characters, not strings, for this function.

Comment: While I don't think this question should stay open, how exactly is it "not reproducible?" I think "Needs debugging details" or "Needs more details" is more appropriate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
if(stoi(val) == c)
```

It seems that you're trying to compare string and an integer

Comment: It works now! Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: @Tim It doesn't at all do what you seem to intent it to do.

Comment: @Tim It compiles now and happens thanks to coincidence to work with your numbers. But it is very unlikely to work with your alpha.

Answer (score -2):

I´m not really sure, but I think you are trying to compare a list with an integer. Maybe are you trying to make `val == lst[c]`?

Comment: Please wait until you have the rep to leave actual comments. Comments as answers will only slow that process down. The comment is also wrong. They are comparing a string to an integer.

Comment: This is not an answer. Soon with enough SO reputation you'll be able to add comments. Until then, avoid posting comments as answers.

Comment: This is an answer. Despite the lack of confidence, it's clearly an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Isaiah Then my downvote would remain as it's completely off-base. OP can feel free to ignore my bits about comments.